# Value from Binding ElementName producing empty string

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, elementname

I have a Datagrid which has a DataGridTemplateColumn containing a ListView whose Itemsource is bound to an array of string.

Within that ListView I have defined an ItemTemplate as I want the Foreground of each item in the list to be dependant on condition - so that's applied to a TextBlock.

I want a tooltip to display when each item in the ListView is hovered over, so I have a Tooltip defined in that TextBlock

What I'm trying to do is have that Tooltip display the title/detail about a specific item by using a converter (to get the index of the item in a different list).

For this I need the Tooltip to know the ListView item but I can't seem to get that to work. The TextBlock itself retrieves it using `Path=.`, I have tried naming the TextBlock `ListItem` and retrieving it as ElementName to no avail - the result is just empty string.

Here's the relevant xaml (with formatting properties removed).

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock x:Name="ListItem" Text="{Binding Path=.}" Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource ConvertItemToColour}}">
            <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ListItem, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource ConvertItemToTitle}}"/> <!-- Item Title -->
                        </Label>
                        <Label>
                            <TextBlock/> <!-- Item Description -->
                        </Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ToolTip>
            </TextBlock.ToolTip>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToolTip`, [like `Popup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749018(v=vs.100).aspx#PopupandtheVisualTree), is not part of the main visual tree so neither `ElementName` nor `RelativeSource` binding will work beyond `ToolTip` but `DataContext` inside `ToolTip` should still be the same as for `ListViewItem`

```
<ToolTip>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <Label>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource ConvertItemToTitle}}"/>
      </Label>
   </StackPanel>
</ToolTip>
```

`Text="{Binding Path=.}"` should give you same result inside `ToolTip` as in `DataTemplate`